# Salesforce Production Site API login fine, but Sandbox API login fails

Tags: api, authentication, salesforce

We've got a working salesforce api implementation that gets and sets properly with a production salesforce account.  We've recently come across a user that rather than using their production Salesforce to connect to our implementation, has set up a sandbox for a limited trial.

I personally have a sandbox that I can properly connect to.  It is not, however, connected to a production salesforce instance.

I'm wondering if the fact that they have a production salesforce instance that they created the sandbox from will affect the API login to the sandbox.

I'm currently receiving a "your salesforce login is incorrect" even though I am absolutely certain the credentials and security token are correct.

If you need any other information, I'll happily include it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Login requests for sandbox accounts should goto test.salesforce.com not login.salesforce.com. You should also login through the webapp and look in login history (in setup) that'll sometimes have more information.

Comment: I'll find out if our implementation points to just login.salesforce.com and let you know what I find.

Comment: This was the problem.  We've added an option to select whether the SF instance is a sandbox or not.  Thanks a ton for the speedy answer!

Comment: PS If you generate the enterprise WSDL XML from within your Sandbox, then your SOAP client will work properly, as the correct URLs are included for Sandbox use.